# Nuxt 3 minified JS files not concatenated into one file

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a standard Nuxt 3 project in production and it seems to fetch all the JS files individually on page load. Each file has been minified but I would expect all of them to have been concatenated into 1 JS file. What setting am I missing or is this not out of the box behavior in Nuxt 3?